# Ruby how to round only higher?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rounding

How can i round in ruby only higher, and so, that 2 last numbers are null?
For exapmle

```
4233.000001 to 4300
52825 to 52900
627444 to 627500
111999 to 112000
```

?

Now i can round only in mathematic-rules via round(-2), but how to do only higher, and only with 2 null's on the end?

Comment: Pseudo code: `ceil(NUM/100)*100`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `ceil`

```
def my_round a
  (a / 100.0).ceil * 100
end

my_round 4233.000001 # => 4300
my_round 52825 # => 52900
my_round 627444 # => 627500
my_round 111999 # => 112000
```

Comment: Ceiling, "rounding always up". :) The opposite function is called `floor`. Now it's obvious, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

working off Sergio's answer, you could mix a module in to the actual `Numeric` object for a more general solution:

```
module RoundsUp
  def round_up(ndigits)
    pow_ten = 10 ** -ndigits
    (self / pow_ten.to_f).ceil * pow_ten
  end
end
```

then

```
mynumeric = 262.33
mynumeric.extend(RoundsUp)
mynumeric.round_up(-2) #=> 300
```

and you've got a method that behaves like the normal `round` for any number of digits

Comment: You could define this as an extension onto `module Float` so that you can write `1.1.round_up` if you like